# I am trying to set action with variable of the form using jquery. It is correctly setting the action, but on the action page there is nothing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is what I am trying to do.

HTML:

```
<form id="search-form" action="search-results.php?a=" method="get">
   <input type="text" id="search-field" autocomplete="off">
   <button type="submit" class="btn fs-search"> <i class="fas fa-search"></i> </button>
   <ul></ul>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
function nameOfFunction(x, y) {
        $("#search-field").val(x);
        x = btoa(x);
        y = btoa(y);
        var ogAction = $("#search-form").attr("action");
        var action = ogAction + x + "&b=" + y;
        $("#search-form").attr("action", action);
    }
```

Thanks for any solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the action page there is nothing"?  Where do you ever call `nameOfFunction`?  Please provide a more complete example demonstrating the problem and clarify what the problem is.

Comment: this is a search field/functionality. The ul in the HTML is populated(as <li>) with the suggestions received from the backend. `nameOfFunction` is called on clicking any of the suggestions(in the form of <li> in the UL tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the form in the wrong way. The `action` cannot pass values, but is only the address where the values should be sent to.

Values of a form are sent by `input` elements in the form. The `name` attribute of the input specifies the key in which the value will be stored on the receiving end.

```
<form id="search-form" action="search-results.php" method="get">
  <!-- name: search -->
  <input name="search" type="text" id="search-field" autocomplete="off">
  <button type="submit" class="btn fs-search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

In your PHP file

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
```

Comment: when I set like this `<form id="search-form" action="search-results.php" method="post">` my problem is solved. Now it is correctly receiving at the backend. Your suggestion also worked.